# remove elements from XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

I have generated an xml file from an excel data base and it contains automatically an element called "`offset`". To make my new file match my needs, I want to remove this element using java.
here is the xml content:

```
<Root><models><id>2</id><modelName>Baseline</modelName><domain_id>2</domain_id><description> desctiption </description><years><Y2013>value1</Y2013><Y2014>value2</Y2014><Y2015>value3</Y2015><Y2016>value4</Y2016><Y2017>value5</Y2017></years><offset/></models></Root>
```

I made a code that reads(with a buffered reader) and writes the content in a new file and used the condition if:

```
        while (fileContent !=null){
        fileContent=xmlReader.readLine();
        if (!(fileContent.equals("<offset/>"))){
            System.out.println("here is the line:"+ fileContent);
            XMLFile+=fileContent;
            }


    }
```

But it does not work

Comment: You would be better off using a proper XML parser like DOM, SAX or StAX. What exactly about the above code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally recommend using a proper XML parser like Java [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) to check and delete your nodes, rather than dealing with your XML as raw `String`s (yuck). Try something like this to remove your 'offset' node.

```
File xmlFile = new File("your_xml.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("offset");
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nList.item(i);
    node.getParentNode().removeChild(node); 
}
```

The above code removes any 'offset' nodes in an xml file.

If resources/speed considerations are an issue (like when your_xml.xml is huge), you would be better off using [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html), which is faster (a little more code intensive) and doesn't store the XML in memory.

Once your `Document` has been edited you'll probably want to [convert it to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567416/document-to-string) to parse to your `OutputStream` of choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace the unwanted string with an empty string. It is quick... and seriously dirty. But might solve your problem quickly... just to reappear later on ;-)

fileContent.replace("`<offset/>`, "");

Answer (score 0):

```
   String sXML= "<Root><models><id>2</id><modelName>Baseline</modelName><domain_id>2</domain_id><description> desctiption </description><years><Y2013>value1</Y2013><Y2014>value2</Y2014><Y2015>value3</Y2015><Y2016>value4</Y2016><Y2017>value5</Y2017></years><offset/></models></Root>";
   System.out.println(sXML);
   String sNewXML = sXML.replace("<offset/>", "");
   System.out.println(sNewXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String xml = "<Root><models><id>2</id><modelName>Baseline</modelName><domain_id>2</domain_id><description> desctiption </description><years><Y2013>value1</Y2013><Y2014>value2</Y2014><Y2015>value3</Y2015><Y2016>value4</Y2016><Y2017>value5</Y2017></years><offset/></models></Root>";
            xml = xml.replaceAll("<offset/>", "");
            System.out.println(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code that you included you have:

```
while (fileContent !=null)
```

Are you initializing fileContent to some non-null value before that line?  If not, the code inside your while block will not run.

But I do agree with the other posters that a simple replaceAll() would be more concise, and a real XML API is better if you want to do anything more sophisticated.