# Empty SOAP Response

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I wrote the below code to send a SOAP request to an endpoint and get the response back. When I ran the code I am getting empty response. May I know what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance. When I sent the same headers in SOAP UI , I am getting back the correct response. I feel some more logic needs to be added to it

```
        package com.siebel.Webservice;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
    import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
    import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

        String endpoint = "https://mywebsite.org/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&WSSOAP=1";
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(createSoapEnvelope(), endpoint);
        System.out.println(response.getContentDescription());
      }





      private static SOAPMessage createSoapEnvelope() throws SOAPException {
           MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
              SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

          SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

          String myNamespace = "arm";
          String myNamespaceURI = "http://siebel.com/Webservice";

          // SOAP Envelope
          SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
          envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);


          //SOAP Header
          SOAPHeader soapheader = envelope.getHeader();

          // Create a header block
          QName username = new QName("http://siebel.com/webservices", "UsernameToken");
          SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = soapheader.addHeaderElement(username);
          headerElement.addTextNode("username");


          QName password = new QName("http://siebel.com/webservices", "PasswordText");
          SOAPHeaderElement headerElement2 = soapheader.addHeaderElement(password);
          headerElement2.addTextNode("password");


          QName session = new QName("http://siebel.com/webservices", "SessionType");
          SOAPHeaderElement headerElement3 = soapheader.addHeaderElement(session);
          headerElement3.addTextNode("Stateless");




          // SOAP Body
          SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
          SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("QueryList_Input", myNamespace);
          SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("SRNum", myNamespace);
          soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("");
          try {
              System.out.println("Soap message is ");
            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          return soapMessage;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your mistake is thinking that SOAPMessage.getContentDescription() is going to just return the SOAP envelope.   Didn't `soapMessage.writeTo(System.out)` show it just fine?

Comment: When I wrote soapMessage.writeTO(Sytem.out) I get the below output           <siebelf:errorcode>SBL-EAI-04313</siebelf:errorcode><siebelf:errorsymbol>IDS_EAI_WS_OP_NOT_FOUND</siebelf:errorsymbol><siebelf:errormsg>There is no active Web Service with operation named &apos;http://siebel.com/Webservice:QueryList_Input&apos;.(SBL-EAI-04313)</siebelf:errormsg></siebelf:error>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a wrong method. The one you call (getContentDescription()) will rather return content of "Content-Description" HTTP header.

Instead, to get a text representation of your SOAPMessage, you need to use some transformer, for example as described here:
[How to convert SOAPBody to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149528/how-to-convert-soapbody-to-string)